# Select only 1 checkbox or a unique set in Checkboxlist asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to to use a checkboxlist because there is a unique case the user is allowed to select 3 items at the same time. Problem is that I can't even manage to get the single selection to work. I'm doing this is codebehind with an updatepanel to not refresh the page.

```
protected void cblCodeRequest_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int maxObjects = cblCodeRequest.Items.Count;
    string[] checkObjects = new string[maxObjects];
    ListItem selectedItem = new ListItem();

    foreach (ListItem item in cblCodeRequest.Items)
    {
        checkObjects[i] = item.Text;
        i++;
    }

    foreach (ListItem item in cblCodeRequest.Items)
    {

        if (item.Selected)
        {
           count++;
           selectedItem = item;
           cblCodeRequest.ClearSelection();
        }


        foreach (ListItem itm in cblCodeRequest.Items)
        {
           if (item.Equals(selectedItem))
           {
              item.Selected = true;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, i already save the selected item and clear the whole selection and then set it again but it doesn't do it, it just selects itself again after even if i click a different checkbox. I think my logic is messed up

Comment: The code does exactly what you tell it to do.It Deselects all items and selects the item again, what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: It is not working as intended, if i selected another item it unselects and selects the previous item again and the rest is unchecked

Comment: Is that what you want it to do or that is what it does with the code above?

Comment: It's what the code does. I just want to uncheck all other elements when i check a different element but keep that element checked, like a radio button. But i can't use radio buttons because there are 3 checkboxes in the group that must be allowed to be checked at same time

Comment: Sometimes when I get stuck with something and don't seem to find a solution, I just delete everything and start over. With a fresh start it will be a slightly different solution and that will often work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Your `foreach` statements are not arranged correctly

```
protected void cblCodeRequest_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem selectedItem = cblCodeRequest.Items[cblCodeRequest.SelectedIndex]


    cblCodeRequest.ClearSelection();

    int x = 0;
    for(x; x<cblCodeRequest.Items.Count; x++)
    {
         if (cblCodeRequest.Items[x].Equals(selectedItem))
         {
             item.Selected = true;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Close but it only works on the items after the selected item. If i select a previous item on the index list it selects it and unchecks again, so i can just go one way in the list. Need to get the last selected item somehow

Comment: now it works backwards lol. I think need to save the selected item on a hidden field and check for it to get the last selected item because it clears all selection when you have 2 selected items, the previous and the one you just select, so the code won't even manage to read  the recent check

Comment: I have edited the answer further, used a for loop instead.

Comment: Maybe you should add an else statement after the if statement then  under it use `item.Selected = false;`

Comment: Thanks but i think i will just do this in javascript so i can remove the update panel. I'm using a hiddenfield to store the last value and will work with that

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally solved this problem. I had to dig through the problem with the debugger and follow the logic. I did this in jQuery so I can remove the update panel. If Anyone ever gets the same problem as me, this is the solution for you.

This allows you to use a checkboxlist like a radiobuttonlist but also allows you to check multiple checkboxes that belong to a special selection group.

```
$(function () {

$('[id*=cblCodeRequest] input').on('click', function () {

    var checkboxlist = $('[id*=cblCodeRequest]'); // CheckBoxList 

    var checkboxArray = $('[id*=cblCodeRequest] input'); // CheckBoxList Items

    var current = $(this); // Get Selected Checkbox 

    var label = $(current).next().text(); // Get CheckBox label name

    // Uncheck every checkBox that don't match the unique multi selection combo

    if (label != "Recâmbio" && label != "Série" && label != "Embalagem Alternativa") {

        // Loop through checkboxArray and uncheck every item that does not meet the condition
        $(checkboxArray).each(function (i) {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });

        // Check the selected item again
        $(current).prop("checked", true);
    } else {

        // Get the current checkbox name 
        var chk = $(current).next().text();

        // If the checkbox that matches the unique combo selection was click uncheck all invalid checkboxes that don't match
        if (chk == "Série" || chk == "Recâmbio" || chk == "Embalagem Alternativa") {

            // loop through the checkboxlist again
            $(checkboxArray).each(function () {
                // Get the looped item name
                var ck = $(this).next().text();
                // if checkbox does not belong to the unique combo selection, uncheck it
                if (ck != "Recâmbio" && ck != "Série" && ck != "Embalagem Alternativa") {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
});
```